# Ordering Dictionaries in a List

Tags: python

I am inserting dictionaries to a list one by one. Eventually I am sorting the list by two values of the dictionaries. Is there a way where the sorting takes place while a new dictionary is inserted instead of doing it at the end? Is there an in-build package or method that lets me do that so every new dictionary is placed right?

Comment: [`bisect.insort()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort), maybe

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried? I don't have experience in Python, but usually dictionaries are not guaranteed to be in the order unless the documentation explicitly says otherwise.

Comment: Although I'd recommend against. `bisect.insort` would be O(n^2) worst case since you have to move everything after the insertion point. Sorting at the end is O(nlogn).

Comment: I am using the ordered dictionary to order my dictionaries by keys which is working fine. Then I am inserting those dictionaries to a list one by one. I am then using "my_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x['key1'], x['key2']))" which works fine too. Now I am trying to do the sorting with every insertion of the dictionary to my list for efficiency.

Comment: That wouldn't necessarily be any more efficient when using a List as the container. If you wanted that, I'd say stick it all in a heap and then both insertion and spitting out the ordered list would be efficient. Worrying about efficiency in Python may or may not be the best use of your time, though. This isn't C.

Comment: btw, an ["Ordered Dictionary"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)  is a specific data structure in python. What you have is a bunch of dictionaries in a list.

Comment: Instead of a keeping the dictionaries in a sorted list, consider putting them in an instance of the [SortedCollection](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) class mentioned in `bisect`'s documentation because it does what you want. Just provide it with a `key` function that compares the two values of interest in each dictionary. Using it would likely be simpler than using `bisect()` directly especially given that it's already been written and debugged. However, as also mentioned, if you don't need things sorted as it's built, just doing it at the end would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `heapq` module, which contains a priority queue implementation (keeps an ordered list while you insert new items). The trouble with this module is, it doesn't let you provide a comparison function for inserting data. We can overcome this limitation by feeding `heapq.heappush` a tuple with the first and second keys and the dictionary we want to store:

```
def make_tup(d):
    return (d['keyA'], d['keyB'], d)
```

Example usage:

```
# Create tuples and add it to the heap queue
ls = []
heapq.heappush(ls, make_tup(dict(keyA=10, keyB=5, c=20)))
heapq.heappush(ls, make_tup(dict(keyA=5, keyB=13, c=5)))
# Iterate over sorted items
for key_a, key_b, value in ls:
    print value
```